# Python function in not throwing error although two return keywords are given

Tags: python

I saw below code in a code review. Python 3.9.

```
def choice():
    x = "Xamaro"
    return x
    y = "Camaro"
    return y
```

When i run the code it is not throwing any error. So i thought that it is returning 2 values.
So i tried to get returning values like below.

```
a, b = choice()
print(a,b)
```

But it throws error : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

If i try below code, it prints "Xamaro" without error.

```
a = choice()
print(a)
```

So it looks like it is getting the first return value. But why doesnt it throw error for second return value for y. Is there a specific usage scenario for this double return usage in python ?

Comment: The statements *after* the first `return` statement are not executed

Comment: I know why only one value is returned, but I am also curious about why it doesn't throw an error when the second one is clearly unreachable. (for example, Java does throw such an error) Is it just a design decision?

Comment: I'm curious... You say you saw this in code review. You mean someone actually wrote this for a project? Or do you mean it was part of some sort of tutorial/puzzle/interview? There'd be no good reason to write code like that for real.

Comment: @shriakhilc I'm unfamiliar with Java, but Python itself never performs static analysis to find unreachable code paths. So there's no way for it to meaningfully distinguish this clearly useless case from situations where you'd actually *want* multiple `return`s in the same function (probably involving an `if` or similar).

Comment: @CrazyChucky Not true. CPython, at least, actually can do some dead-code elimination.

Comment: It makes sense if they aren't looking for it, probably just not a priority. Java does allow sensible cases (where only one return will ever trigger the exit), but it throws an `error: unreachable statement` in cases like this question (since no branching).

Comment: @chepner Fair enough, I stand corrected. Do you mean in things like compiler optimization? Does it ever use if for anything that could, like the asker brings up, raise an error?

Comment: A general rule of language design is to not explicitly prohibit things simply because there's no apparent use for it. Dead code isn't always so obvious to detect, so you either *allow* all dead code, or risk trying to spend an excessive amount of time *finding* all dead code to flag as an error. Optimizations like eliminated dead code that can be found with a "reasonable" amount of effort are a good compromise between the two approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am also curious about why it doesn't throw an error when the second one is clearly unreachable.

Rather than throw an error for unreachable code, the compiler can simply eliminate it.

```
>>> def choice():
...     x = "Xamaro"
...     return x
...     y = "Camaro"
...     return y
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(choice)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Xamaro')
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

(An even smarter compiler could note the immediate load following the store and generate `LOAD_CONST 1; RETURN_VALUE`, but CPython apparently does not make the effort to perform such optimizations.)

This is not to say that Python will eliminate *all* dead code, but it also means the language does not commit itself to detecting it, either. The body of a function is just a list of valid statements without worrying about whether every such list makes sense, and leaving it at that simplifies both the parser and the code generator.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, only `x` is returned.  The function stops when it hits the first `return` statement.  To return both, you would need to do this:

```py
def choice():
    x = "Xamaro"
    y = "Camaro"
    return x, y
```